# Requesting object property

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I extract the '2013' value from this object?

And for future reference, how do I request a list of all properties of a jQ object instead of just getting [Object object] in console when I do console.log(thisYear) in this case?

```
<div id="parentEle">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1">
      <span class="year">2013</span>

var thisYear = $('#parentEle').first('.year'). ??;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var thisYear = $('#parentEle').find('.year:first').text();
```

Comment: I get text output of the entire contents of #parentEle... not just 2013 (coming from the first occurrence of 'year' class